# should question about HTML5 be on topic?

Tags: discussion

I would say that asking about HTML5 is not within the scope of the site, as opposed for example to EPUB3: but I'd like to know what other think about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it will depend on the context of the HTML5 question, but in many cases, yes. For example, many web-based reader software, such as the Kindle Cloud Reader and the Kobo Cloud Reader are developed in HTML5.

There is a decent blog [here](http://goodereader.com/blog/electronic-readers/feature-are-ebook-apps-html5-or-epub3-the-future-of-digital-publishing) about the relevance of HTML5 (and EPUB3) in the future of electronic reading.

Quick intro excerpt:

> Digital Publishing is one of the fastest growing segments and most
>   major publishers are now seeing 21% of their total revenues stem from
>   it. Publishers cannot decide on what the future of publishing will
>   entail. There are three main aspects that the vast majority of
>   companies employing for their strategy. We are seeing strong growth
>   with dedicated e-reading apps, HTML5, and ePub3/ePub2 as the main
>   factors for content delivery. In the next three weeks, we will be
>   talking to some of the leading digital publishers that are currently
>   living in this space. They will be talking  about the future and
>   current state of digital publishing and how the industry will look in
>   2013-2014.

Answer (score 4):

Ebook authoring is considered one of the on-topic areas of the site. By extension, so too will be HTML(5) in the context of writing ebooks. Questions purely about HTML would be off-topic here.

Comment: +1 for *"in the context of writing ebooks"* and I think you should emphasize that part? By extension, off-topic examples would include questions about http, servers, domains, SEO, etc.?